# Error parsing query can't understand why

Tags: c#, sql

```
 SqlCeConnection con1=new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication6\\WindowsFormsApplication6\\Database1.sdf");
 con1.Open();

 SqlCeDataAdapter com1=new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from Customer where Size No = "+textBox1.Text,con1);

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 com1.Fill(dt);

 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
 con1.Close();
```

Comment: Where are you getting a error? What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Because of that `Size No`

It shouldn't have a space but an underscore or whatever as long as it's your column name.

Comment: Or surround it with brackets if it really has a space: `[Space No]`